# What is the typealias in Android Studio project?

Tags: android, kotlin

The code  A comes from the [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs.git).

1:  What is the `typealias` in Android Studio project?

2:  Is the `typealias` keyword of Kotlin?

3: Is there a equivalent code as same as `typealias OnExploreItemClicked = (ExploreModel) -> Unit` ?

4: Why is the code `typealias OnExploreItemClicked = {(ExploreModel) -> Unit }`  wrong?

**Code A**

```
typealias OnExploreItemClicked = (ExploreModel) -> Unit

@Composable
fun CraneHome(
    onExploreItemClicked: OnExploreItemClicked,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
     ...
}
```

Comment: It's in the Kotlin documentation. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-aliases.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the typealias keyword of Kotlin?

Yes.

> Is there a equivalent code as same as typealias OnExploreItemClicked = (ExploreModel) -> Unit ?

No. However, given that statement, `OnExploreItemClicked` is the equivalent code to `(ExploreModel) -> Unit`. In other words, your example could also be written as:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CraneHome(
    onExploreItemClicked: (ExploreModel) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
     ...
}
```

> Why is the code typealias OnExploreItemClicked = {(ExploreModel) -> Unit } wrong?

Because the right-hand portion of the `typealias` statement needs to be a *type*, not an *object*. You are attempting to have `OnExploreItemClicked` be a (syntactically-invalid) lambda expression, not a type.

> What is the typealias in Android Studio project?

A `typealias` is an alias for a type. Rather than having to use `(ExploreModel) -> Unit` in function parameters and similar places, you can use `OnExploreItemClicked`. In some cases, the alias may be shorter. Ideally, the alias is more descriptive of what the type really means. In this case, `OnExploreItemClicked` suggests that the type is used for a callback when an "explore item" is clicked.

You can read more about `typealias` in the "Functional Programming" chapter of [my free book on Kotlin](https://commonsware.com/Kotlin/).

Answer (score 1):

1. **What is the typealias in Android Studio project?**

See item #2 response.

2. **Is the typealias keyword of Kotlin?**

From [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-aliases.html):

> Type aliases provide alternative names for existing types. If the type name is too long you can introduce a different shorter name and use the new one instead.

3. **Is there a equivalent code as same as typealias OnExploreItemClicked = (ExploreModel) -> Unit ?**

No. But in this code, `OnExploreItemClicked` is equivalent to `(ExploreModel) -> Unit`. So instead of writing the longer `(ExploreModel) -> Unit`, you can just use the defined alias.

4. **Why is the code typealias OnExploreItemClicked = {(ExploreModel) -> Unit } wrong?**

Because of the brackets. After adding them, you are creating a lambda function, that cannot be assigned to `OnExploreItemClicked` because it requires a type.

In summary, it is just a way to create a new name for a type. Example:

```
typealias Str = String

fun main() {
     val myStr: Str = "I'm still a String"
     println(myStr::class.simpleName) // This will print "String" to the output
}
```